# How to add multiple signers on a single document using docusign REST API Embedded Signing

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web application developed which we want to sign a sales contract pdf from the end customer. It’s a responsive web application which can be used from desktop/laptop, tablet or mobile phones.

I am trying to implement Embedded Signing with multiple signer using docusign REST API.
So the flow in my app is the following:-

1. Dealer goes to the sold to party and sold to party will sign.
2. Dealer goes to the payer and payer will sign.
3. And finally dealer will do the final signing and all the signer will receive the signed document via mail.

**My app status-**

1. I have successfully created signing url for first signer and signing is completed and returning to my web page.
2. But for the second signer i want to sign on the first signer url.But it is redirecting to web page.

**My scenario is -**

Is this possible without opening three recipients views - one for the sold to party, one for the payer and one for dealer? Can we achieve this just by opening one view where all recipients can sign the order with mobile verification authentication?

In one signing url all the signer will complete the sign process with mobile verification authentication.

I tried to add a single recipient with three signing boxes with mobile verification authentication. But after complete the first signer it is returning to main web page.

**Please check this scenario also-**

My question is is there any way this is possible? I am assuming that it isn't since each envelope id can really only relate to a single signer. It doesn't even make sense to me how a second signer could sign the same document with the same envelope id and put in different data and it maintain the integrity of both signers since envelope id seems to be a sort of session for the document.

Please help me Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to open separate signing ceremonies for each signer.  Each captive recipient (for embedded signing) is defined by their email, name, and clientUserId.  ClientUserId needs to be unique to each individual, such as a customerId in your system.  If you don't have a unique identifier for each person, then simply use their email address.

You should also consider how you will validate the identity of the person signing and link it to the DocuSign signing, since DocuSign is not sending an email link for validating who was invited in.  You can link that data using the additional parameters for the createRecipient Envelope View API call, i.e. assertionId, authenticationInstant, authenticationMethod, and securityDomain.

Comment: My Question is-

1) How we can validate the first signer has completed the sign document using embedded DocuSign after returning to main web page.

Comment: For the signer themselves, you will get an "event" code appended to the redirect following signing.  This is good for knowing where to take that signer post-signing.  
For knowing that the first signer is complete, the best approach is to use the Connect service (webhook). Register for notifications on recipient-completed.